# O conteúdo dos Enums estão chegando nulos ao banco de dados [Java + Spring boot + JPA + Hibernate + PostgreSQL]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho 3 enums e nenhum deles está sendo salvo no banco após submeter o formulário (os outros campos sim). Já coloquei a anotação @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) nos campos e ainda assim não resolveu.
Segue abaixo os trechos de código relevantes:

***Enum:***

```
public enum Turno
{
    MATUTINO("Matutino"),
    VESPERTINO("Vespertino"),
    NOTURNO("Noturno"),
    INTEGRAL("Integral");
    
    private final String descricao;
    
    Turno(String descricao)
    {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getDescricao()
    {
        return descricao;
    }
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group offset-md-3">
        <label>Turno:</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{turno}">
            <option th:each="turno : ${T(br.com.academy.enums.Turno).values()}"
                    th:value="${turno}" th:text="${turno.descricao}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</div>
```

***Entidade:***

```
@Entity
public class Aluno {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    
    private String nome;
    
    private String matricula;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Curso curso;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Turno turno;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
    
    /* Getters e Setters dos outros atributos omitidos*/

    public Turno getTurno()
    {
        return turno;
    }
}
```

***PostMapping no Controller***:

```
@PostMapping("cadastrarAluno") /* Anotação para enviar dados */
public ModelAndView cadastrarAluno(Aluno aluno)
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("redirect:/aluno/listAlunos");
    repositorio.save(aluno);
    return mv;
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer onde está o erro?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema: havia confundido o fato dos atributos de um Enum não possuírem setters com o Enum em si como atributo de uma entidade possuir setter ou não e com isso percebi que havia apagado os setters do Enum na entidade Aluno. Desse jeito era óbvio que não ia settar no banco de jeito nenhum!kkkkkkk
Peço desculpas pelo problema idiota.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).